# wx.FileDialog doesn't set directory

Tags: wxpython, openfiledialog

I am trying to open a file dialog to a directory other than the one in which I am working. I tried this:

```
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", style=wx.FD_OPEN)
dlg.SetDirectory("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\Circuit Design Tool\Program Files")
dlg.ShowModal()
file_name = dlg.GetPath()
dlg.Destroy()
```

and this:

```
directory = "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\Circuit Design Tool\Program Files"
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", directory, style=wx.FD_OPEN)
dlg.ShowModal()
file_name = dlg.GetPath()
dlg.Destroy()
```

but they both open to the directory in which I am working. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with wxPython:

Try using this path with e. g. `open(...)` and it will also not work.

Reason: Som backslash/byte combinations will result in interpretation as [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), e. g. `"\t"` as tab character. To avoid this, you can declare the string as "raw" with the `r` prefix, like this:

```
"\t" == r"\t"
```

Of course, if you are on windows and the path contains unicode characters, it will get interesting again :)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
dataDir = r"C:\Users\tech\Desktop\Circuit Design Tool\Program Files"

with wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', dataDir,
                  style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as dlg:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                dbfilename = dlg.GetPath()
                dataDir, dbFile = os.path.split(dbfilename)
```

Don't know why SetDirectory does not work, but in the other one you are not giving a default dir, see:
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/FileDialog.html?highlight=filedialog#api-class-api

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but since it might help others with the same problem:

As nepix32 correctly explained, the backslashes need to be escaped. I found that this is still insufficent to get it working, but it started to work once I included an additional trailing backslash, so both this:

```
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", style=wx.FD_OPEN)
dlg.SetDirectory("C:\\Users\\long\\path\\to\\Program Files\\")
```

and this:

```
directory = "C:\\Users\\long\\path\\to\\Program Files\\"
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", directory, style=wx.FD_OPEN)
```

work for me (note the trailing `\\` at the end of the path).

If you use this, a raw string isn't sufficient to disambiguate a last backslash from a literal quote sign, so you have to escape the backslashes instead. Or use forward slashes.